# What is the number..?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-theory

This is a short number puzzle:

> Find a number $x$, which leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $2,3,4,5$ and $6$.

Here is the some more explanation:
$x$ divided by $2$ gives remainder $1$
$x$ divided by $3$ gives remainder $1$
$x$ divided by $4$ gives remainder $1$
$x$ divided by $5$ gives remainder $1$
$x$ divided by $6$ gives remainder $1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brute force, everyone.

There are 1.667 correct answers just between 1 and 100.000

You may check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g4tk05pn/

So while the question is not spesific like `smallest number possible`, there is not just one answer.

Comment: Cool.. nice try..!!!! and got it worked..!! cheers..!!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple, it's 61.

LCM of 2,3,4,5,6 (which is 60), plus 1.

Comment: Who would down-vote this?

Answer (score 4):

The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) renders this type of problem easy.  However, in this case the answer is even easier:

> The answer is $1$, since:
>  $$ 1~\text{mod}~2 \equiv 1 \\ 1~\text{mod}~3 \equiv 1 \\ 1~\text{mod}~4 \equiv 1 \\ 1~\text{mod}~5 \equiv 1 \\ 1~\text{mod}~6 \equiv 1 $$

The Chinese remainder theorem tells us that there are an infinite number of numbers satisfying this type of system of equations.  There is a bit of difficulty in that our moduli are not pairwise coprime, so we must take the least common multiple of the moduli instead of just multiplying them:

> $\text{LCM}(2,3,4,5,6)=60$, so our final answer is $x\equiv 1~\text{mod}~60$

Comment: Note that you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ChineseRemainder%5B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%7D%5D) to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's 721, or in other words, 6! + 1.

Comment: 1 is the trivial solution. If you add more numbers in the factorial, eg. 7! + 1, 8! + 1, etc, you'll have infinitely many more solutions.